# JSON Schema enum does not affect validation

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a sub-schema defined in nested objects and cannot make the enum constraint work. See here....

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Top level": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "State": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "description": "stuff",
                    "properties": {
                        "Value": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum:": [
                                "A",
                                "B",
                                "C"
                            ]
                        },
                        "readOnly": true
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "Value"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "State"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "Top level"
    ]
}
```

This should fail but instead it validates. Below...

```
{
    "Top level": {
        "State": {
            "Value": "not supposed to validate but does anyway"
        }
    }
}
```

Oddly, this schema appears to work and block the undesired strings but it does not have the deeper sub-schema structure...

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Value": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and this example properly gets rejected...

```
{
    "Value": "D"
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? It must be something fundamental about nested objects.I know if I change the Value name, it detects it is missing and rejects during validation in the first example... why does it not detect the invalid enum strings ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was really hard to spot for some reason. I thought I was going nuts too. You've got an extra `:` in there.

```
"enum:": [
     ^
```

Comment: AAAARRRRGGGGHHHH ! Yeah, that's it. Thank you so much !